powerBI / DAX — SUM values in one table based on IF conditions in another table
I have two tables coming from different sources, with different refresh frequencies.
• Table_1 is used to classify various Orders into groups (monthly update, with K's lines of data).
• Table_2 is the work reported by employees (daily updates, M's lines of data).
A simple connection between tables would make this task easy.
However, in Table_1 the Orders are split into two columns: Quote# and Order#.
And, in Table_2 everything is grouped into a single column.
I'm trying to create a SUMIF based on IF conditions, which would functions similar to this:
Contact_Hours = 
/* if the Quote didn't turn into an Order */
if 'Table_1'[Order#] = ""
then sumx(filter(Table_2; [WorkOrder] = 'Table_1'[Quote#]; [ContactHours]))
/* if Quote became an Order */
else if sumx(filter(Table_2; [WorkOrder] = 'Table_1'[Order#]; [ContactHours]))
/* if there's "crazy data" */
else "Nothing found"

Is this even possible in PowerBI / DAX?
I tried putting if-then / else if-then / else inside CALCULATE, but that wasn't successful.
Also tried with a simple IF:
IF(
    ISBLANK(Table_1[Order#]);
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table_2[ContactHours]); Table_2[Project] = Table_1[Quote#]);
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table_2[ContactHours]); Table_2[Project] = Table_1[Order#])
)

But it throws an error:

"The expression contains columns from multiple tables, but only columns
from a single table can be used in a True/False expression that is
used as a table filter expression."

=== a crude , but working solution ===
One way to solve this — is to use 2 helper columns in Table_1 :
• One helper column to calculate the ContactHours for anything in Quote# column corresponding to Table_2[Project]:
ContactHours_Quote = 
    CALCULATE(
            SUM('Table_2'[ContactHours] );
            FILTER( 'Table_2';  'Table_2'[Project] = 'Table_1'[Quote#])
    )

• Then in the second helper column do the same for Order# :
ContactHours_Order = 
    CALCULATE(
            SUM('Table_2'[ContactHours] );
            FILTER( 'Table_2';  'Table_2'[Project] = 'Table_1'[Order#])
    )

• Finally, add up the results of the helper columns:
[ContHrs_Qte]+[ContHrs_Ord]

A bonus effort would be to add a step in PowerQuery to replace any "weird" or empty entries in the Quote# and Order# columns with something like " -- " .


What is the structure of your two tables? Since you state "However, in Table_1 the Orders are split into two columns: Quote# and Order#. And, in Table_2 everything is grouped into a single column.", it could be possible to create a new column (in Power Query or more upstream) that also combines Quote# and Order# into one column. As such, you could create a relationship and your calculation would be a lot easier.
Some simple screenshots of a sample of the data would be useful.
